# How to avoid Ember from freezing when the DOM is being rendered

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, handlebars.js

I see my navigation and other components freeze (not responding to hover/click events) for some seconds..  after model for a particular route has been fetched..
Has encountered something on like this?

Possibly it is because of the DOM being rendered...
Any idea how can i avoid that?

Same thing happens, when I load more items and append it to DOM..

I am on ember-cli@0.1.15 with ember version 1.8.1

Comment: Can you recreate the issue in a JSbin or something like that?

Comment: Are you making synchronous AJAX calls?

Comment: Are you trying to add a large umber of items to the DOM, such as a table with thousands of rows? This can result in UI freeze until complete. If so, you may be able to solve with render chunking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript can freeze when Ember is rendering complex templates or when Ember Data receives massive data dumps. This freezing inherent to JS being single-threaded and can not be solved, but it can be avoided by optimising your code!

## How to optimize templates:

1. **First analyse** using the Performance tab in the [Ember Inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ember-inspector/bmdblncegkenkacieihfhpjfppoconhi?hl=en). Look for the components that take longest to render and tackle those first. Alternatively use [Perforator](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/perforator-ember-performa/hfdilejiecmablifdkololalnbbmdcdb/related), a Chrome Extention that will show you rendering times for each view / component.
2. **Use [Ember.run.next()](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html#method_next) to spread out big operations** into the next cycles. This works much like `setTimeout()`, but with Ember integrations.
3. **Replace:** `{{link-to 'route'}}` with `<button {{action 'openRoute'}}>`. Rendering link-to's requires way more performance to render than simple HTML with Ember action. Made massive difference to our project because we had hundreds on one page.
4. **Avoid re-rendering where possible.** For example: instead of sorting a list by sorting the array of objects and then rendering them again with `{{#each}}`, use CSS3 flex to sort. This requires no JS and thus no freeze.
5. **Keep Ember up-to-date.** Ember's rendering engine (Glimmer) is improved continuously.
6. **Use [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)** to render your HTML in the background (quiet advanced).

## How to optimize big data:

1. Consider loading model relations asynchronously instead of including them.
2. Load only the data shown to the user (pagination).
3. Shorten the data sent.

More suggestions welcome!

Comment: Good set of suggestions **if** rendering were the problem. Concerning web workers, interesting idea, but I thought they could not access the DOM? One more thing--having each of 1K objects rendered using deeply nested components will kill you--consider flattening your component structure if that could be an issue.

Comment: Here is a state of the art example of Ember + web workers (= lightning fast rendering and animations). It's complex but not impossible. http://www.pocketjavascript.com/blog/2015/11/23/introducing-pokedex-org

Answer (score 0):

You need to do more benchmarking to confirm your hypothesis that the problem is rendering. Actually, I would guess the problem is at least as likely to be in loading the data. Instrument your code to detect this:

```
model() {
  console.time("modelStart");
  var data = this.store.query(...;
  data.then(() => console.timeEnd("modelStart");
  return data;
}
```

The above timing will be a combination of server latency and local processing by Ember Data once the data has arrived. Obviously, the browser does not freeze while waiting for a server response. To determine the time required **after** data arrives to process it and populate the store, you could subtract from the time reported the approximately server latency as found in the network tab, which should be good enough, or, if necessary, you could instrument more deeply to find the actual time being taken by Ember Data.

Comment: Requesting the model does not freeze the UI for `this.store.query` returns a promise. Whether it takes 200ms or 5 seconds for the server to return the data, the rest of your JS will keep running. You'll see, from the second the model resolves and the big chunk of data is fed to the template, that's when JS goes into overdrive and can potentially freeze the UI for a few 100ms.

Comment: I am not talking about server latency. I am talking about the work required to get the data populated into the store once it arrives. I speak from deep experience, since in our case we were downloading and populating the store with a thousand complex records with many associations, which Ember Data took up to 20 seconds to process, during which the browser was very much frozen.

Comment: Interesting point, we never had to deal with such big data. Do you have tips on how to tackle / manage big data? Surely there are way to trim, paginate or async big data?

Comment: You could avoid Ember Data for this part of the code. Alternatively, you could write your own adapter which asynchronously pushes chunks into the store. Or, you could paginate on the server.